# How does Android achieve the attribute "wrap_content"?

Tags: android, view

These days I am learning how to customize the view on Android.I know if we set the minimum width, then the system will compare the min width we set and the measured width and choose the proper one to fit the view.What I am confusing is that how does android system change the size of the view according to the content of the view as the word "wrap_content" means.I want to know more details about how to achieve "wrap_content". Thanks a lot.

Comment: here is your answer http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/how-android-draws.html

Answer (score 0):

This is what [Official Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/how-android-draws.html) says (I am adding just a part of it for a quick read)

When a View object's `measure()` method returns, its `getMeasuredWidth()` and `getMeasuredHeight()` values must be set, along with those for all of that View object's descendants. A View object's measured width and measured height values must respect the constraints imposed by the View object's parents. This guarantees that at the end of the measure pass, all parents accept all of their children's measurements. A parent View may call `measure()` more than once on its children. For example, the parent may measure each child once with unspecified dimensions to find out how big they want to be, then call `measure()` on them again with actual numbers if the sum of all the children's unconstrained sizes is too big or too small (that is, if the children don't agree among themselves as to how much space they each get, the parent will intervene and set the rules on the second pass).

The measure pass uses two classes to communicate dimensions. The `ViewGroup.LayoutParams` class is used by View objects to tell their parents how they want to be measured and positioned. The base `ViewGroup.LayoutParams` class just describes how big the View wants to be for both width and height. For each dimension, it can specify one of:

`MATCH_PARENT`, which means the View wants to be as big as its parent (minus padding)

`WRAP_CONTENT`, which means that the View wants to be just big enough to enclose its content (plus padding).

`MeasureSpec` objects are used to push requirements down the tree from parent to child. A `MeasureSpec` can be in one of three modes:

`UNSPECIFIED`: This is used by a parent to determine the desired dimension of a child View. For example, a `LinearLayout` may call `measure()` on its child with the height set to `UNSPECIFIED` and a width of `EXACTLY` 240 to find out how tall the child View wants to be given a width of 240 pixels.

`EXACTLY`: This is used by the parent to impose an exact size on the child. The child must use this size, and guarantee that all of its descendants will fit within this size.

`AT MOST`: This is used by the parent to impose a maximum size on the child. The child must guarantee that it and all of its descendants will fit within this size.